# Is it possible to toggle ReadOnly on a CheckBox column in an ASP.NET GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have an asp:CheckBoxField column in a asp:GridView.
I would like to make that column ReadOnly if it is already checked.
That field gets populated from a bool value in the database.

So far, I've only been able to set the ReadOnly property of the column during design time.  When I have attempted to set it dynamically in code, it doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Is there anyway to reference the "ReadOnly" property of the Checkboxes inside of the GridView?

[image]

Comment: yes you can definitely reference the value a you should have an event for the EditLinkButton something like this `LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)lnk.NamingContainer;
                string tempID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();` once you get the row you're on you can get or set the checkbox value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this through gridviews row data bound event

```
<asp:gridview id="Gridview1" runat="server" onrowdatabound="Gridview1_RowDataBound" ..........>
```

and in code behind

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkBox");
            if (chk.Checked==true)
            {
                chk.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Sruthi.  I actually attempted to use that code but it didn't work.  I put a breakpoint on that event, it never got called.

Comment: @MatthewWalk - I've had that issue before with it not firing. Have you tried adding `<asp:gridview id="Gridview1" runat="server" onrowdatabound="Gridview1_RowDataBound">` to the control?